# Selenium issues with Telerik RadMenu

Tags: css, asp.net, selenium, telerik

Since last 2 days i am working on finding the best possible way to write integration tests for my asp.net website using Selenium without any luck.

I am using Telerik RadMenu which is something like this -

```
Root Menu 
- Menu 1
  - Sub Menu 1.1 
  - Sub Menu 1.2
- Menu 2
  - Sub Menu 2.1
- Menu 3
  - Sub Menu 3.1
  - Sub Menu 3.2
  - Sub Menu 3.3
```

The way it works is - user hovers over `Root menu` which opens `Menu` and using hover it opens `Sub Menu` and clicking on it opens Telerik dialog box.

I tried couple of ways to perform 2 hovers and a click which looks like this -

Method 1:

```
Actions action = new Actions(Browser.Driver);
IWebElement we = Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadMenu1']"));
action.MoveToElement(we).MoveToElement(we.FindElement(By.XPath("ul/li/div/ul/li[1]"))).Build().Perform();
action.MoveToElement(we.FindElement(By.XPath("ul/li/div/ul/li[1]/div/ul/li[1]"))).Click().Build().Perform();
```

Method 2:

```
var advFilter = Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadMenu1"));

    Actions action = new Actions(Browser.Driver);
    var advFiltersPrimary = Browser.Driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".rmLevel1>li"))[0];
action.MoveToElement(advFilter).MoveToElement(advFiltersPrimary).Build().Perform();
    var advFiltersSec = Browser.Driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".rmLevel2>li"))[0];
    action.MoveToElement(advFiltersSec).Click().Build().Perform();
```

The generated HTML looks like this -

```
<div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadMenu1" class="RadMenu RadMenu_Default " style="z-index: 7000;">
    <ul class="rmHorizontal rmRootGroup">
        <li class="rmItem rmFirst rmLast" style="z-index: 0;"><a href="#" class="rmLink Menulevel1" id="advMenu" style="color:White;background-color:#7F5EBA;" tabindex="-1"><img alt="" src="../../images/icons/addFilters.gif" class="rmLeftImage"><span class="rmText rmExpandDown">Root Menu</span></a><div class="rmSlide" style="visibility: visible; height: 301px; width: 260px; display: none; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: -301px; z-index: 2;">
            <ul class="rmVertical rmGroup rmLevel1" style="width: 258px; display: block; top: 301px; left: 0px; visibility: visible;">
                <li class="rmItem rmFirst" style="z-index: 0;"><a href="#" class="rmLink " style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); border-color: rgb(195, 195, 195); width: 254px; background-color: white;" tabindex="-1"><span class="rmText rmExpandRight">Menu 1</span></a><div class="rmSlide" style="visibility: visible; height: 210px; width: 214px; display: none; overflow: hidden; left: 258px; top: 0px; z-index: 16;">
                    <ul class="rmVertical rmGroup rmLevel2" style="display: block; width: 212px; top: 0px; left: -214px; visibility: visible;">
                        <li class="rmItem rmFirst"><a href="#" class="rmLink " style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); border-color: rgb(195, 195, 195); width: 208px; background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);" tabindex="-1"><span class="rmText ">Sub Menu 1.1</span></a></li><li class="rmItem"><a href="#" class="rmLink " style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); border-color: rgb(195, 195, 195); text-decoration: none; width: 208px; background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);" tabindex="-1"><span class="rmText ">Sub Menu 1.2</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div></li><li class="rmItem" style="z-index: 0;"><a href="#" class="rmLink " style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); border-color: rgb(195, 195, 195); width: 254px; background-color: white;" tabindex="-1"><span class="rmText rmExpandRight">Menu 2</span></a><div class="rmSlide" style="visibility: visible; height: 279px; width: 225px; display: none; overflow: hidden; left: 258px; top: 0px; z-index: 16;">
                    <ul class="rmVertical rmGroup rmLevel2" style="width: 223px; display: block; top: 0px; left: -225px; visibility: visible;">
                        <li class="rmItem rmFirst"><a href="#" class="rmLink " style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); border-color: rgb(195, 195, 195); width: 219px; background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);" tabindex="-1"><span class="rmText ">Sub Menu 2.1</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div></li><li class="rmItem" style="z-index: 0;"><a href="#" class="rmLink " style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); border-color: rgb(195, 195, 195); width: 254px; background-color: white;" tabindex="-1"><span class="rmText rmExpandRight">Menu 3</span></a><div class="rmSlide" style="visibility: visible; height: 233px; width: 271px; display: none; overflow: hidden; left: 258px; top: -40px; z-index: 16;">
                    <ul class="rmVertical rmGroup rmLevel2" style="display: block; width: 269px; top: 0px; left: -271px; visibility: visible;">
                        <li class="rmItem rmFirst"><a href="#" class="rmLink " style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); border-color: rgb(195, 195, 195); width: 265px; background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);" tabindex="-1"><span class="rmText ">Sub Menu 3.1</span></a></li><li class="rmItem"><a href="#" class="rmLink " style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); border-color: rgb(195, 195, 195); width: 265px; background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);" tabindex="-1"><span class="rmText ">Sub Menu 3.2</span></a></li><li class="rmItem"><a href="#" class="rmLink " style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); border-color: rgb(195, 195, 195); width: 265px; background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);" tabindex="-1"><span class="rmText ">Sub Menu 3.3</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div></li>
            </ul>
        </div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In 2nd method i am using rmLevel1 and rmLevel2 css class since telerik assigns rmLevel1 to `ul` for `Menu` and and it assigned rmLevel2 class to `ul` for `Sub Menu`.

The problem is Method 1 works only sometimes(most of the times it just fails at the `Sub Menu` level hover execution) and Method 2 selects 2nd element even when i specify 1st element. In other words it selects incorrect element from the list.

Please help with the better way of doing this.

Comment: Please share the HTML for this first where you want to perform hover...

Comment: Just updated the question with generated html

Comment: Could you tell me where hover event works means on on `ul` or `li` or `a`...??

Answer (score 0):

```
var advFilter = Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadMenu1"));
Actions action = new Actions(Browser.Driver);
var advFiltersPrimary = Browser.Driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".rmLevel1>li"))[0];    
action.MoveToElement(advFilter).MoveToElement(advFiltersPrimary).Build().Perform();
var advFiltersSec =  Browser.Driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".rmLevel2:nth-of-type(2)>li"))[0];
action.MoveToElement(advFiltersSec).Click().Build().Perform();
```